# Using a nail file on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, parts-of-the-body, boneh-soter

According to Halacha, is one allowed to file their nails with a nail file on Shabbat? Would this fit into a specific melacha that is prohibited? Source for this would be appreciated

Comment: Probably forbidden on account of *memachek* (see [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Memachaik#Cleaning_Under_One's_Nails) regarding indirect scraping), and maybe also (rabbinically?) on account of *tochen*.

Comment: Possibly also *gozez*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to Rabbi Dovid Ribiat's *[The 39 Melochos](https://www.feldheim.com/the-39-melochos-1)*, Vol. III p.680

> Cutting or removing fingernails or toenails with an instrument (even a knife) is Gozez M'deoraisa. **Similarly, filing one's nails is also Gozez M'deoraisa because the tiny shavings are removed with an instrument**.

The Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa, also says like this albeit without a specified reason. (See the [Feldheim English Edition](https://www.feldheim.com/shemirath-shabbath), Vol. I, 14:54, p.162)

> On Shabbath and Yom Tov one is not allowed to cut, trim or file nails, whether with scissors, a nail file or any other instrument or by biting them.